# getting error while trying to create a react app

Tags: reactjs

I used to create react apps with the facebook's github repo and it worked each time, but this time it is not working. Because I'm getting this error and I can't find the reason behind it. I've already tried to do the cache clean.

```
> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\user\Desktop\cryptohello\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.12 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-15T16_48_09_293Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting cryptohello/ from C:\Users\user\Desktop
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't support of `fork`, `exec` and `bash` in `cmd` in windows, please try with `GIT Bash`

Comment: or to install the react app with git bash?

Comment: install react app with git bash

Comment: only node_modules file is installed with git bash

Comment: Please run the `npx create-react-app my-app` from the git bash

Comment: uninstall node_modules and use yarn to create your react app or use stable node version